# Sum of Values with Strings

Tags: excel

I have multiple columns that contain a sample information as listed below:

```
  A  |  B  |  C  |  D
------------------------
 23R | 12C |  4D | 35R
 12C | 76T | 14T | 19D
 32C | 56D | 14R | 68D
 ... | ... | ... | ...
 etc | etc | etc | etc
```

From the whole table (without creating another column), I would like to sum up all the values that contain the letter "R". Given the example table above, the number should be: 72. I've tried a multitude of different approaches:

- Doing a straight sum will yield "0" (as expected)
- Tried splitting the letter from the number with a LEFT/RIGHT/LEN combination, but that required another column
- Using SUMIF will only work with numbered ranges (unless someone can show me to apply a function beforehand without an additional column)
- SUMPRODUCT did not help
- Looked into vlookup/hlookup. Didn't yield any desired results

How can I achieve this without any additional columns? Cells can also be blank, and I would like to handle them as zeros if possible.

Comment: Are you ok with a macro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(RIGHT(A2:D4,1)="R",VALUE(LEFT(A2:D4,LEN(A2:D4)-1)),0))
```

A2:D4 is your entire table.  Enter the formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Excellll has provided a nice formula way of doing it. Here is a VBA function that will do the same. You would call it like this:

```vb
=CountR(A2:D4)  'in your example becomes 72
```

code:

```vb
Function CountR(ByVal cell_range As Range) As Long

Dim i As Long, j As Long, total As Long
Dim varray As Variant
varray = cell_range.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(varray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(varray, 2)
        If Right$(varray(i, j), 1) = "R" Then
            total = total + Left$(varray(i, j), Len(varray(i, j)) - 1)
        End If
    Next
Next

CountR = total

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. I will keep this VBA function for future use for when I dive deeper into this spreadsheet.